# Show either chart or table based on radio button or checkbox in ssrs

Tags: checkbox, reporting-services, radio-button

**I have a report request to show either chart or table using SSRS**. I am mew to SSRS so not sure of woraround to make this work.

So far I tried below:
1. Create a "ShowDetails" parameter with 
Data type - Boolean
Parameter Visibility - True
Available values - none
Default Values (non queried)- =False

2 In the chart properties set the Hidden to -> =Not(Parameters!ShowDetails.Value)
and toggle to textbox1 which I created for expand and collapse option.

Problem is radio button is not working ie., when I change the option to true no action on chart.Have to control the chart only by expand and collapse option.

Looking for other solution to show either chart or table based on show or hide parameter.

Thank You
Shilpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write the expression in the Hidden Property of the chart like this instead.

```
=IIF(Parameters!ShowDetails.Value="False",True,False)
```

Comment: Thank you i did modify the code as above with some alterations and its working. I will post the solution tomorrow

Thank You
Shilpa

Answer (score 0):

The above expression with some work around got me the answer. Below are the steps

1. Create a "ShowDetails" parameter with Data type - Boolean,Parameter Visibility - True Available values - Label-No, Value -True and Label-Yes, Value -False  Default Values (non queried)- =True

2 In the chart properties set the visibility->Hidden -> =IIF(Parameters!ShowChart.Value="1",True,False)

With the above solution am able to hide and show the chart based on input parameter.

Thank You
Shilpa